# Is there a way to have a text file be broken into characters and pass this into an arrayList which then is fed as a parameter to a method?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following pieces of code and I am attempting to create an ArrayList 'list', which takes in 'ch' from the text file for each element i. The ArrayList then is fed as a parameter to the method of 'HelloPrinter' class.

I am getting no errors, but the 'reverse.txt' file isn't reversing the lettering as it is suppose to with the 'recursiveReverse' method.

Test/Driver:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Class;

public class HelloPrinterDriver
{
    public static void  main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int i = 1;


        File inputFile = new File("src/reverse.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
        in.useDelimiter("");

        //System.out.println(list.getClass().getSimpleName());
        //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("src/reverse.txt");

        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            char ch = in.next().charAt(0);
            list.add(ch);
            i++;
        }

        HelloPrinter.recursiveReverse(list);


        in.close();
        //out.close();


    }

}
```

Class:

```
    import java.util.*;

public class HelloPrinter
{
    public static String recursiveReverse(ArrayList<Character> str)
    {
        Stack<Character> st = new Stack<>();

        for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++)
            st.push(str.get(i));

        for (int i=0; i<str.size(); i++) {
            str.set(i,st.peek());
            st.pop();
        }
        return String.valueOf(str);// converting character array to string
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Method `recursiveReverse` is not recursive because it does not use _recursion_. 2. Results of calling `recursiveReverse` are not stored in a variable / used anywhere else. 3. The characters inside `list` are reversed successfully upon calling `recursiveReverse`.  4. File `reverse.txt` is not rewritten with the reversed contents.

Answer (score 0):

This should provide the result you are seeking:

```
    @Test
    public void test2() throws FileNotFoundException {
        final ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();

        final File inputFile = new File("src/test/resources/reverse.txt");
// Scanner implements AutoCloseable so we can wrap it in a try and it will be closed automatically for us.
        try (final Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile)) {
            in.useDelimiter("");

            while (in.hasNext()) {
                final char ch = in.next().charAt(0);
                list.add(ch);
            }
        }
        // Now reverse the order of the characters in the list.
        Collections.reverse(list);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(list));
    }
```